# Add HTTP referer to admin's Online Customers

Tags: magento-1.9, customer

Is it possible to add **HTTP referer** to **Customers>Online Customers**, in the admin area?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible. Before you get started though you may want to check your *log_visitor_info* table to determine if the data is worth adding. I've found that more often then not the data recorded is not very helpful.

Looking in: /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Online/

The best way to handle this is to create a new module to override the core functionality.

Alternatively you can copy the files in that directory to:
/app/code/**local**/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Online/

After that though, you need to figure out how to get the data from the *log_visitor_info* table as I'm not entirely familiar with that process right now. The current row provided to the rendering classes contains the following fields:

- visitor_id
- visitor_type
- remote_addr
- first_visit_at
- last_visit_at
- customer_id
- last_url
- customer_lastname
- customer_middlename
- customer_firstname
- customer_email

You will need to modify Grid.php *_prepareCollection* function to pull in the additional data (notice that right now it's pulling the first 7 fields from the *log_visitor_online* table, then it adds the customer data with the call to *$collection->addCustomerData()*) and the *_prepareColumns* function to set up the grid columns. Then you'll just need to create a renderer for the new data.